# Is saying "How many percent...?" incorrect?

Tags: word-choice, percentages

Our students are often asked to describe a chart for their online classes. We have to ask follow-up or guide questions to help them describe it and I often ask my students about how many votes did an item in the chart get. So, is it incorrect to say:

"***How many percent*** of votes did Sheriff Woody get?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct wording is "**What percentage of** votes..."

This is because a percentage is a singular item. It is *one* percentage no matter what the number in the percentage is. *1%* is a percentage, *50%* is a percentage, and so on.

So when you're referring to a percentage, you say *what* to signal a singular item instead of *how many* which signals multiple items.